# Changes to C++ explicit casts

Tags: c++, casting, type-conversion, c++20

I have not gotten my hand on C++20. Are there any changes to C++ explicit cast operators (`static_cast`, `dynamic_cast`, `const_cast` and `reinterpret_cast`) in C++20? That is, any improvements, deprecations or new casts? For instance, any improvements to make `reinterpret_cast` less error-prone?

Comment: `std::bit_cast` is added to the STL and requires that source and destination are of the same size.

Comment: How could one make `reinterpret_cast` less error-prone?  It exists to (temporarily) lie to the compiler.

Comment: "_I have not gotten my hand on C++20_" - Perhaps the [C++20 - final draft](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/N4860.pdf) is good enough?

Comment: @DavisHerring exactly, `reinterpret_cast` only exists as a cast of last resort when none of the others will do what you need.  It should only be used when you're 100% sure of what you're doing.  I wonder if there are compilers that will generate a warning every time you use it?

Comment: Thanks folks for your insightful comments and @Ted Lyngmo for the link. Gracias.

Answer (score 6):

There aren't any major changes to explicit casts, but one noteworthy one is:

- [P1327R1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p1327r1.html): *Allowing dynamic_cast, polymorphic typeid in Constant Expressions*

which allows `dynamic_cast` in constant expressions.

The other change related to casts is the introduction of `std::bit_cast`:

- [P0476R2](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0476r2.html): *Bit-casting object representations*